# In Clojure, how do I send an exit command to a process created by Clojure.java.shell/sh

Tags: shell, clojure, pocketsphinx

I am trying to run pocketsphinx from clojure. I have written the following .sh script

`unbuffer pocketsphinx_continuous -innmic yes > pipe` and I want to call this process using (shell/sh).

Unbuffer allows pocketsphinx to properly flush its data out to pipe where it can be read line by line.

The problem I am having is I do not know how to properly kill the process. It will run forever and never return control. If I kill the thread it is running on, the process that the sh command spawned still runs. The only thing I can think of is running `kill` on the `pid`

Comment: It is better to use pocketsphinx through Java API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clojure.java.shell/sh` won't return until the process being executed completes and you would need to use another thread to use kill on a pid.

Another solution would be to use [`java.lang.Runtime.exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) or [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)to get a [`java.lang.Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) instance which provides methods like [`destroy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy--) or [`destroyForcibly`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroyForcibly--).

You can also use a [Raynes/conch](https://github.com/Raynes/conch) library if you still would like to have a nice Clojure API and still be able to run a command and specify a [timeout for the process to complete and still get the output produces until the timeout occured](https://github.com/Raynes/conch#buffering).